# How to create instance of org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, exception

I need to create JUnit test for handling of DataAccessException,

but when I try:

```
            throw new DataAccessException();
```

Receive:

```
 Cannot instantiate the type DataAccessException
```

Why? What can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

*DataAccessException* is an abstract class and can not be instantiated. Instead use one of the concrete classes such as *new DataRetreivalFailureException("this was the reason")* or create your own:

```
throw new DataAccessException("this was the reason") {};
```

And you get an anonymous class derived from the DataAccessException.

Comment: I was trying to throw `NonTransientDataAccessException`, which extends `DataAccessException` but is also **abstract**. I can now throw `DataRetrievalFailureException`, which extends `NonTransientDataAccessException` and is not **abstract**. Thanks, your answer really helped me.

Answer (score 6):

> Why?

Simply because `DataAccessException` is [abstract class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html). You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

> What can I do?

If you check the hierarchy:

```
extended by java.lang.RuntimeException
              extended by org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException
                  extended by org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException
```

Since `NestedRuntimeException` is also abstract, you can throw a `new RuntimeException(msg);`(which is not recommended). You can go for what the other answer suggests - Use one of the concrete classes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Using TransientDataAccessException.class , this can be used

```
 doThrow(new TransientDataAccessException("Oops! Something went wrong.") {}).when(myMock).callSomeMethod(param1,param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking into source code, you will notice it's an **abstract class**, look into that:

```
package org.springframework.dao;

import org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException;

public abstract class DataAccessException extends NestedRuntimeException {
    public DataAccessException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

    public DataAccessException(String msg, Throwable cause) {
        super(msg, cause);
    }
}
```

And as you know abstract classes can not be extended...

But you can use it in other ways, this is one way to use it for example:

```
public interface ApiService {
    Whatever getSomething(Map<String, String> Maps) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to return Mono.error with a DataAccessException in my test mock. I **instanciated a anonymous class** of the abstract class and it worked for me:

```
Mono.error(new DataAccessException("exception message"){})
```