# junit5 mockito jdbctemplate when always returning null

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I've a jdbcTemplate call returning some object. The unit test is always returning null.

```
public Person retrievePerson(String lastName,
  long id) {
try {
  return jdbcTemplate
      .queryForObject(GET_PERSON_DETAIL,
          new Object[]{lastName, id},
          (rs, rowId) -> new Person(rs.getString("ssn"),
              rs.getString("phoneNo")));
} catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {
  throw new PersonNotFoundException(
      "no database records exists for the given lastName " + lastName
          + " and id " + id + " the actual error message is "
          + dataAccessException.getMessage());
}
}
```

The corresponding unit test

```
  @Test
  void testRetrievePerson() {
  // Setup
  final Person expectedResult = new person(
    "111111111", "1234567890");

  // Configure JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(...).
  final Person person = new Person(
    "111111111", "1234567890");
  //    when(mockJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(eq("sql"), any(Object[].class), 
  //any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(person);
 doReturn(person).when(
    mockJdbcTemplate).queryForObject(eq("sql"), any(Object[].class), any(RowMapper.class));
// Run the test
final Person result = personClassUnderTest
    .retrievePerson("lastName", 0L);

// Verify the results
assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expectedResult);
}
```

I tried both when method and doReturn. I am always getting the resuly as null. Also, the other test to cover DataAccessException `java.lang.InstantiationError: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException`

Comment: Have you added `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` on top of your test class?

Comment: `eq("sql")` could this be `any(String.class)` ?  Also expectedResult should be new *P*erson

Comment: No. I tried adding and ran the test got `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:  - this invocation of 'queryForObject' method:
    mockJdbcTemplate.queryForObject() ` followed by a very long error message

Comment: @JohnMitchell that really worked. changing from `eq("sql")` to `any(String.class)` 

Still for my line coverge... for the`DataAccessException` I'm getting `java.lang.InstantiationError: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException

Comment: Can you show the code for the DataAccessException test that is troubling you? This thread may be useful; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178728/how-to-create-instance-of-org-springframework-dao-dataaccessexception/11178828

Comment: I was able to instantiate  using `doThrow(new DataAccessException("no record exists"){}).when()....`

But, these lines are not covered for some reason 

`(rs, rowId) -> new Person(rs.getString("ssn"),
              rs.getString("phoneNo")));`

Comment: the reason I believe was using `any(RowMapper.class)` but in the original method it was   a lamda func. I tried couple of things but it didn't work.